# SQL Incorrect Syntax Error

Tags: sql

*Here I have two tables Site and SiteCoordinate.
    and other tables are connected with each others.

```
    Site.UniqueIDName,       /* Site table with different fields */
    Site.Name AS SiteName, 
    Site.MarkerName, 
    Site.MarkerNumber,
    SiteCoordinate.LocationLat,   /* SiteCoordinate Table with Different field */
    SiteCoordinate.LocationLong, 
    SiteCoordinate.LocationHeight,  /* I need to display both tables records */
```

Create and Insert Data into tables.

**Error:**

I found an error incorrect syntax near ON and Where.

```
FROM   SiteCoordinate **ON** SiteCoordinate.SiteID ON Site.ID = SiteCoordinate.SiteID Left OUTER JOIN /* Syntax error */   /* is this the correct syntax */
        vwStationConfiguration RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        vwSite RIGHT OUTER JOIN   /* Outer Join */ 
        Site ON vwSite.ID = Site.ID ON vwStationConfiguration.SiteID = Site.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN  /* Outer Join */ 
        vwSiteSensorInformation ON Site.ID = vwSiteSensorInformation.SiteId LEFT OUTER JOIN  /* Outer Join */ 
        Person RIGHT OUTER JOIN  /* Outer Join */ 
        SiteContact ON Person.ID = SiteContact.PersonID ON Site.ID = SiteContact.SiteID LEFT OUTER JOIN         
        Agency ON SiteContact.AgencyID = Agency.ID
WHERE   (SiteContact.SupportLevel = 1  or SiteContact.SupportLevel is NULL)
```

The above code is example of Inner Join and outer Join. Before this FROM   SiteCoordinate **ON** SiteCoordinate.SiteID ON Site.ID = SiteCoordinate.SiteID Left OUTER JOIN // the program is working properly but after this line found an error.

And second thing

```
**:XML ON**    /* incorrect syntax near ':'. */
```

Comment: write the query which you are running

Comment: FROM   SiteCoordinate ON SiteCoordinate.SiteID ON Site.ID = SiteCoordinate.SiteID Left OUTER JOIN
vwStationConfiguration RIGHT OUTER JOIN
vwSite RIGHT OUTER JOIN   
Site ON vwSite.ID = Site.ID ON vwStationConfiguration.SiteID = Site.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN vwSiteSensorInformation ON Site.ID = vwSiteSensorInformation.SiteId LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Person RIGHT OUTER JOIN SiteContact ON Person.ID = SiteContact.PersonID ON Site.ID = SiteContact.SiteID LEFT OUTER JOIN //Agency ON SiteContact.AgencyID = Agency.ID
WHERE   (SiteContact.SupportLevel = 1  or SiteContact.SupportLevel is NULL)

Comment: I found one more error :XML ON (Incorrect Syntax Error Near ':' )

Comment: write the full query from Select what exactly you are executing copy it properly.

Comment: You are missing the `JOIN` keyword: `FROM   SiteCoordinate JOIN SiteCoordinate.SiteID ON ...`

Comment: You seem to be asking a number of queries which seem to revolve around basic SQL syntax. They should be relatively easy to resolve yourself by *starting simple* and *building things up* until the query has the shape you need. I.e. start by querying a single table. Then add *just one more table* and make sure that's working correct, that your join *works*, etc.

Comment: DECLARE @ServerName as nvarchar(32)

CREATE TABLE #myServer(
 [ServerName] nvarchar(64) NULL,
 [ServerType] nvarchar(12) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #mySites(
 [ServerName] nvarchar(64) NULL,
 [UniqueIDName] nvarchar(5) NULL,
 [SiteName] nvarchar(17) NULL,
 [MarkerName] nvarchar(61) NULL,
 [MarkerNumber] nvarchar(21) NULL,
 [LocationLat]  nvarchar(21) NULL,
 [LocationLong] float NULL, 
 [LocationHeight] float NULL,

Comment: /* Create Table */
CREATE TABLE #mySites(
 [ServerName] nvarchar(64) NULL,
 [UniqueIDName] nvarchar(5) NULL,
 [SiteName] nvarchar(17) NULL,
 [MarkerName] nvarchar(61) NULL,
 [MarkerNumber] nvarchar(21) NULL,
 [LocationLat]  nvarchar(21) NULL,
 [LocationLong] float NULL, 
 [LocationHeight] float NULL
);